# Print two array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have one echo join that prints the values ​​of an array. But i need this echo join prints the first array + the second array.

Example: 
array1: 1,2,3
array2: a,b,c

Result: 1a,2b,3b etc..

I have a cicle while that analyzes all the records in a table and places them in the two arrays . How can I do to ensure that the echo join molds both the array?
Thanks to all!

Comment: You need to add the code you currently have and what you've tried.

Comment: Writing some code would be a good start.

Comment: Please improve your Quest..

Comment: Loop over one array, and use the index to get values from both.

Comment: I was thinking of `array_combine` and worked out the answer, but then I see that your first array is not symmetrical to the second. You can't tell which value of the first array belongs to the one in the second. So more information is needed that will give you that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try to mix those arrays in one associative array like:

```
array('A' => 1, 'B' => 2);
```

Then you do a foreach and print the key and the value.